# How do I create a Jetpack Compose Column where a middle child is scrollable but all of the other children are always visible?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a Jetpack Compose Dialog that contains a Column where all of the elements should always be visible, except for the third element, which is a Text that should be scrollable if the text doesn't fit the screen space. I almost achieved this with a secondary scrollable Column just for that Text element. However, this implementation pushes the bottom child (a button) out of view if there is a lot of text. Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WelcomeView(
    viewModel: WelcomeViewModel,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {
    Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismiss) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(Spacing.extraLarge))
                .background(Colors.backgroundBase)
                .padding(all = Spacing.medium)
        ) {
            Column {
                IconView(
                    name = IconViewNames.RUNNING_SHOE,
                    size = IconViewSizes.LARGE,
                    color = Colors.primaryBase
                )

                Text(
                    viewModel.title,
                    style = Text.themeBillboard,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = Spacing.medium)
                )

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                ) {
                    Text(
                        viewModel.message,
                        style = Text.themeHeadline,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = Spacing.medium)
                    )
                }

                Button(
                    onClick = onDismiss,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(Spacing.medium))
                        .background(Colors.primaryBase)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        "Continue",
                        style = Text.themeHeadline.copy(color = textExtraLight),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(all = Spacing.extraSmall)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewWelcomeView() {
    WelcomeView(
        viewModel = WelcomeViewModel(
            firstName = "Wendy",
            htmlWelcomeMessage = PreviewTextFixtures.threeParagraphs
        ),
        onDismiss = {}
    )
}
```

This is what it (correctly) looks like when there is only one paragraph of text:

[image]

But this is what it looks like when there are three paragraphs. The text scrolls correctly, but notice the missing "Continue" button:

[image]

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Use this for your middle (scrollable) composable

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
) {
     Text("Your text here")
}
```

The key is to use `fill = false`.

Comment: property "weight" under the modifier of "Column" does not exist!

Comment: Sure it does, this column is within another column, so it has a ColumnScope receiver.

Answer (score 43):

Just apply to the scrollable `Column` the `weight` modifier.
Something like:

```
    Column (verticalArrangement= Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
            Text(
                "viewModel.title",
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .weight(1f, false)

            ) {
                Text("...")
            }

            Button() 
            
        }
```

Comment: Oh wow that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Actually when I add this, it looks correct if I have a large amount of text, but for a small amount of text, the Column still stretches out too far, expanding the parent view to maximum height and causing a visual gap between the bottom of the scrollable text and the button.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems getting my form using Column to scroll when the keyboard was showing, then I realized that the entire screen fit into the display, though it was covered with the soft keyboard.  The solution was to make each of the form items into LazyColumn, then add add an item consisting of the empty space that a keyboard would take.

didn't scroll:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState) { 
     .....  //myform
}
```

scrolled when keyboard showed up:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

LazyColumn() { 

   item{
     //form item
   }
   

   item { 
     Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height((configuration.screenHeightDp * .4f).dp))
   
   }
 }
```