# Vertical scroll affecting the modifier weight in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want my button to be bottom of the screen using `Column`. When I am trying to smaller device my content is not scrollable. So I search in stack overflow and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166668/18958467). When I am adding

```
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
```

in my modifier it breaks the spacer weight stuff and placed my button to top.

**Input**

@Composable

```
fun Input() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Item()
    }
}
```

**Item**

```
@Composable
fun Item {
    Image()
    Text() // more item here
    Pressure()
}
```

**Pressure**

```
@Composable
fun Pressure() {
      var value by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
         mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
      }
    Column {
        Text(value)
        Image()
        // more item here
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        OnSubmit(value)
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

I want my button to be bottom with vertical scroll in smaller device.

**UPDATE**

After @SemicolonSpace I tried code and my button is behind from the screen

```
fun Input() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ){
          Column(
              modifier = Modifier
                  .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                  .padding(10.dp)
          ) {
              Item()
          }
          // behind from screen
          OnSubmit()
       }
    }
```

You can see my button is behind the screen, I cannot scroll

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where exactly you face the issue. I made a sample with similar structure as in the images and looks like it works fine if i'm not missing anything.

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Left")
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
            Text("Right")

        }

        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Left")
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
            Text("Right")

        }

        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Left")
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
            Text("Right")
        }

        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Left")
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
            Text("Right")

        }

        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Left")
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
            Text("Right")

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Button(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xff4DD0E1),
                contentColor = Color.White
            )
            , onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text("Submit", modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 20.dp))
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know but your way is working fine... I just copy paste your code.

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73402144/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

Final Working Code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BlogPostsTheme(darkTheme = false) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MyUI()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    val longText = """
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    """.trimIndent()

    
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            // your UI here
            Text(
                text = longText,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }

        // your button here
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.BottomCenter),
            onClick = { }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution it's not working.

Comment: I updated the code. Try it.

Comment: I updated my code as well. Can you please guide me on this. You put my `Button` from `Pressure` composable to parent `Column`. So please guide me my new changes to get value

Comment: note: `value` is just one property for example. I have so many property. which are passing value to my Submit function.

Comment: why not hoisting the `value` to its parent composable, all the way to `Item()` ?

Comment: Ohh yeah I can do that..

Comment: my button is not visible

Comment: Remove the `fillMaxSize()` of the child `Column`. I updated the code.

Comment: vertical scroll not working in small devices..

Comment: Please see my `UPDATE` section. I added image as well. @SemicolonSpace

Comment: I messed up terribly. The parent layout should be `Box`. Put the scrollable `Column` and `Button` inside a `Box` and put the `Button` at the bottom. See the updated code. I tested it. It's working fine. If the buttton overlaps, add a bottom padding to the scrollabe `Column`.

Comment: I really appreciate it.