# Stick Item at bottom of screen in smaller screen in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to stick item at bottom of screen. I did this in larger screen without any problem with the help of this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73280279/11560810). Now I want to stick item in smaller screen, but above stack overflow answer is not working in smaller screen.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 240, heightDp = 432)
@Composable
fun PreviewCompose() {
    Theme {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

        ) {
            Text(
                "Parent 1",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 75.sp
            )
            Text(
                "Parent 2",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 75.sp
            )
            Text(
                "Parent 3",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 75.sp
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Column() {
                Text(
                    "Child 1",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
                    color = Color.White
                )
                Text(
                    "Child 2",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

I am adding my youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/6vZc3Zf5U1o) to understand.

**Expected Output**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about the question. Do you want to have Child1/2 fixed at the bottom and parent1/2/3 scrollable?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
){
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .weight(1f)                    
        ) {
           //Parent1/2/3
        }

        Column() {
            //Child 1/2
        }

}
```

[image]

Comment: It work but I need to remove `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` from 2nd Column

Comment: Yes, my bad. It is a typo