# Reuse of column with duplicate code in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-column

I have composable function in there’s some code is duplicate in `if - else` condition. Both `if - else` have same type of UI but different component. Inside `if - else` UI logic is similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694805/11560810). I want same UI logic in here.

**Xyz**

```
@Composable
fun Xyz(
    isTrue:Boolean,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(true) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement
        ) {
            if (isTrue) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                        .weight(1f),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    Image() // Duplicate code
                    Text() // Duplicate code
                    Image()
                    // more item in here
                }
                Column {
                    Button { action }
                    Button { action }
                }
            } else {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                        .weight(1f),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    Image() // Duplicate code
                    Text() // Duplicate code
                    Image()
                    // more item in here
                }
                Column {
                    Button { action }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding `@Preview` code for some understanding

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun XyzPreviewTop(){
    Theme {
        Xyz(false, Arrangement.Top)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun XyzPreviewSpaceBetween(){
    Theme {
        Xyz(false, Arrangement.SpaceBetween)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun XyzPreviewOneSpaceTop(){
    Theme {
        Xyz(true, Arrangement.Top)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun XyzPreviewOneSpaceBetween(){
    Theme {
        Xyz(true, Arrangement.SpaceBetween)
    }
}
```

1. Inside `if - else` condition I had mention `Duplicate code` which means that code is using in both condition.
2. How can we optimise `if` condition of both `Column` with `else` condition of both `Column`.

If you have question please ask me. Many Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of `isTrue` exactly? Regardless, you should be able to move the if-statement to _inside_ where the composables would differ (i.e. the composable with one/two `Button`s respectively)

Comment: You can have a single `Column` moving the `if-else` inside, using ax external composable for the duplicate `Image`s

Comment: @Edric `IsTrue` is kind of Bluetooth state i.e. **ON** and **OFF** on that bases I am showing UI.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can you please give me example for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [slot-based layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#slot-based-layouts) of Jetpack Compose which increases reusability a lot.

Slot is basically creating content:  `@Composable () -> Unit` like params like  Scaffold, TopAppBar and other Composables have.

```
@Composable
fun Xyz(
    isTrue:Boolean,
    content: @Composable ()-> Unit,
    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(true) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement
        ) {
            if (isTrue) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                        .weight(1f),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    content()
                }
                Column {
                    Button {  }
                    Button { action }
                }
            } else {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                        .weight(1f),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    content()
                }
                Column {
                    Button { action }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you also create a ColumnScope receiver for content: `@Composable ColumnScope.()-> Unit` which will let you call scope specific modifiers like `Modifier.weight` inside your content

Comment: Aha!, so thats what its called!

Comment: :) Yes, they call them slots.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot.. I got the idea..

Comment: @Thracian Is my question topic is correct? or should I change?

Comment: I think it's correct, what do you wish to change about it?

Comment: Nothing I am just asking.. Thanks

Comment: @Thracian can you please look at [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74701726/11560810)