# AutoScroll the behind item in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a **3** `Column`. In **1st** `Column` of components are **2nd** and **3rd** `Column`. In **2nd** `Column` there are so many components inside that. In last **3rd** `Column` I have a few items and I am sticking at the bottom of screen. I have done with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694805/11560810). In smaller screen item is going behind, so my supervisor mention that all item will automatically scroll of **2nd** `Column` which is clearly above of **3rd** `Column`.

```
@Composable
fun Xyz(){
    Theme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.margin_screen_edge_sides))
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
//            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
            or
//                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .weight(1f),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                // so many item in here.
               //  If here items is behind of 3rd column then automatically scroll the item when user land of this this screen
            }
            Column {
                Button()
                // may be more item in here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

**Scenario 1**

[image]

> Note:- Item will be increase in `2nd Column` i.e. I added logic in `AnimatedVisibility` so when recompose it will added the item.

**Scenario 2**

When no item is going behind the **3rd** **Column** then my screen will not scroll anything

[image]

if you have question please ask me. Many Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
@Composable
fun Xyz(){
    Theme {
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

        LaunchedEffect(
            keyOneIsTrue,
            keyTwoIsTrue
        ) {
            val newValue = scrollState.maxValue
            scrollState.animateScrollTo(newValue)
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.margin_screen_edge_sides))
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
//            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
            or
//                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                    .weight(1f),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                // so many item in here.
                //  If here items is behind of 3rd column then automatically scroll the item when user land of this this screen
            }
            Column {
                Button()
                // may be more item in here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have so many `keys` but I am giving you few example in my `LaunchedEffect`. When `keyOneIsTrue` it goes inside the `LaunchedEffect` and then `newValue` always return `0` value. This is same happening in `keyTwoIsTrue` and nothing will scroll :(

> **Note** when any key change it means I am changing visibility of items in **2nd** `Column` by the help of `AnimatedVisibility`

**UPDATE 2**

I am adding real time example which is auto scrolling are not working when item is added in the list.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 250, heightDp = 320)
@Composable
fun Xyz() {
    Theme {
        var itemClicked by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        val favourites = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
        LaunchedEffect(favourites.size > 0) {
            scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.margin_screen_edge_sides))
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                    .weight(1f),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                favourites.forEach { text ->
                    Text(
                        text = text,
                        fontSize = 30.sp,
                        color = Red
                    )
                }
            }
            Column {
                Button(onClick = {
                    itemClicked++
                    favourites.add("item clicked $itemClicked")
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Add me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can clearly see in [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/kk2bcjj0mIw?feature=share) when item add in the list the auto scroll is not working. It only scrolling when user do manually.

Comment: block inside `LaunchedEffect(favourites.size > 0)` gets invoked on composition then when size is greater than 0. It doesn't matter what current size is as LaunchedEffect is concerned. You need to use favorites.size as key. Or call scroll when you add items. In this messaging sample i scroll to last message when new message is added. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Flexible-Chat-Box/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/dynamicmessagebox/DemoFullChat.kt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ScrollState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ScrollState) to scroll the content of the `Column`.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

Column(
   //...
){
    Column(
        Modifier
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    //....
}
```

Then you can use your favorite logic to scroll the content.
For example when the screen is loaded:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
    scrollstate.animateScrollTo(scrollstate.maxValue)
}
```

If you have a list and you want to scroll when a new item is loaded inside the scrollable `Column`:

```
val favourites = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

LaunchedEffect(favourites.size) {
    scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
}
```

[image]

Comment: nothing is working, I have added my code in UPDATE section.

Comment: In **1st** `Column` to change?

Comment: @vivekmodi Sorry. I am not sure about your question. You should avoid nesting components scrollable in the same direction. Why do you need the scroll also in the 1st column?

Comment: I don't wont to scroll 1st Column. In your previous comment you mention to change something, so I was confused and then I asked where should I change. So I guess you are saying in 1st Column.

Comment: In any case in my code the only 1 scrollable column.

Comment: I'll add more code with video, so you can clearly check what is the problem. Give me some time. Thanks

Comment: can you please look now? I have added the code in **UPDATE 2** section. Thanks