# stack a button inside a Column to the bottom of a screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to place a button at the bottom of the screen. If there are a lot of items, the Column scrolls and the button is pushed down. If not, the button should remain at the bottom of the screen as shown below:

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ActionButton() {
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier

            .fillMaxWidth()
            .then(modifier) // to pass Modifier.weight(1f) but it totally hides it from view
    ) {
        Button(
            
            onClick = { log('called') },
            modifier =
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 5.dp)
                .height(24.dp),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Proceed")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a Screen that calls a Step composable with uses the above button.

```
@Destination
@Composable
fun OrderScreen(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator
) {
 Column(
            modifier =
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(12.dp),
        ) {
         StepOne()
      }

}


@Composable
fun StepOne() {
 Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        modifier =
            Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .imePadding(),
    ) { 
       Text(text="Step One")
       
       // other elements
       ActionButton(modifier=Modifer.wieght(1f))

      }

}
```

Comment: you can try this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694805/8266651).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the expectation. If not, please do add a comment.

[image] 
[image]

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    ) {
        repeat(51) {
            Text(text = "Item $it")
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1F),
        )
        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
    }
}
```