# How to make a nested Column scrollable within a Box in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, nested-scroll

My goal is to have Column A fixed and non-scrollable, while Column B should be scrollable when its content overflows the available space. I'd like to achieve this without using LazyColumn.

Is there a way to make Column B scrollable within the Box layout while keeping Column A fixed? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose UI where I have a layout structure like this:

```
Box {
    Column A {
        // Content including text and another Column B
      Column B {
        // Content including text, sub-columns, and more text
        // Column B should scroll
      }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164883/how-do-i-create-a-jetpack-compose-column-where-a-middle-child-is-scrollable-but) answer your question?

Comment: When you want nested Column with scrolling only solution to give them fix height.